# What minimum level of credentials are normally required to join a member server to the domain?

Tags: active-directory

I was installing Server2003 Std and Server2008 Std on hardware recently.  When joining the servers to the domain during the install, I was asked for credentials.

I answered with the the DC's Admin user and password.

***What minimum level of credentials are normally required to join a member server to a domain?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default a domain user can add up to 10 computers to a domain. There is a way that administrators can restrict this default behavior to only allow Administrators to add computers to the domain, by using ADSI Edit.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243327

Answer (score 2):

By default **Authenticated Users** are assigned this privilege.

This is defined by a GPO:

`Computer Configuration --> Policies –-> Windows Settings –-> Security Settings –-> User Rights Assignment -->  Add workstation to domain`

As noted by @redknight, by default users (excepting domain admins) are able to join 10 computers to a domain.

Answer (score 1):

"Add computers to domain" is not restricted to Domain Admins at all, that wouldn't be very good security. There is also no distinction between adding a workstation, or adding a member server.

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251335/) describes some of the details.